# Node module to fetch/post API data

Tags: javascript, beginner, node.js

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and Node and am wondering if I'm on the right track.

Module file:

```
'use strict';

var chalk = require('chalk');
var config = require('../config');
var moment = require('moment');
var rp = require('request-promise');

var todayDay = moment().format('dddd'); // ["Monday"]" 
var todayDate = moment().format('DD').replace(/^0+/, ''); // "1"
var todayMonth = moment().format('MMMM'); // ["January"]

rp({
  method: 'GET',
  uri: config.api.uri + '/tasks',
  qs: {
    access_token: config.api.accessToken,
    project_id: config.api.projectId,
    page_size: 5
  },
  json: true
})
  .then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    var data = res.data;

    data.forEach(function(val) {

      // day is today or date and month is today
      if (val.custom_fields.custom_353.indexOf(todayDay) > -1 ||
        val.custom_fields.custom_356.indexOf(todayMonth) > -1 && val.custom_fields.custom_358 == todayDate) {

        // post 
        rp({
          method: 'POST',
          uri: config.api.uri + '/incidents',
          qs: {
            access_token: config.api.accessToken
          },
          body: {
            item: {
              name: val.name,
              description: val.description,
              due_date: moment().toISOString(),
              assigned_to: {
                type: val.assigned_to.type,
                id: val.assigned_to.id
              },
              project: {
                id: config.api.projectId
              },
              custom_fields: {
                custom_361: val.custom_fields.custom_384, // sequence
                custom_352: val.custom_fields.custom_270, // time
                custom_354: val.custom_fields.custom_269, // procedure
                custom_277: val.custom_fields.custom_183, // service group
                custom_278: val.custom_fields.custom_184 // service
              }
            }
          },
          json: true
        })
          .then(function(res) {
            console.log(chalk.green(val.name));
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(chalk.red(err));
          });
      } else {
        console.log(chalk.grey(val.name));
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(chalk.red(err));
  });
```

Config file:

```
'use strict';

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config = {};

switch (env) {
  case 'development':
    config = require('../env/development/config.json');
    break;
  case 'production':
    config = require('../env/production/config.json');
    break;
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var todayDate = moment().format('DD').replace(/^0+/, ''); // "1"
```

Looks like you're taking a zero-padded day of month here... and then stripping off the leading zero.

You should use [`moment().format('D')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/), it will give you day of month without a leading zero.

Aside from that... you shouldn't use multiple instances of `moment()`. What if the time changes between the two lines of code? You might get things like 31 February.

```
var todayMoment = moment();

var todayDay = todayMoment.format('dddd'); // ["Monday"]
var todayDate = todayMoment.format('D'); // "1"
var todayMonth = todayMoment.format('MMMM'); // ["January"]
```

Like so, both problems are fixed.